# Long time white-screen loading react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-dom

Currently, I am checking a code that uses reactJS as a library with ReactDom. This uses an HTML template and to render components a js file like this:

```
//...
ReactDOM.render(<Component1 />, container1)
ReactDOM.render(<Component2 />, container2)
//...
ReactDOM.render(<ComponentN />, containerN)
```

Whole content rendered at the same time and since every component demand api calls, there is a white-screen at least 2 or 3 seconds.

I guess some reasons:

- The critical path is paused until the whole JS is executed and wait to update the DOM content. So maybe I need only split js and load using async mode (but I do not want to request a lot of js files neither). Currently, someone tried to put all ReactDom.Render calls in an array like tasks and uses an async library to run every call simultaneously but it did not work (delay is not removed)
- Components use other internal components that required finish their own loading process. In this case, I guess I need lazy loading, but since I am using react like the library I am not sure how to do it. Each component uses redux.connect to connect other stateless component and this last use sometimes another's components who call redux actions (API requests) using props.

Comment: Do you use redux-dev-tools as a middleware?

Comment: @Pavel, could you provide more than this, for example, your root `index.js` file. Are you using Promises?